# run a .msi file in java

Tags: java, windows-installer

So I try to run a .msi file like I would an exe file, which may be the problem. I get this error message

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "\": CreateProcess error=193,
>   %1 is not a valid Win32 application

```
       try {   Runtime rf = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
                   Process pf = rf.exec("\\IE8fix.msi");    
                } catch(Exception e) {                 
                    System.out.println(e.toString());                 
                            e.printStackTrace();
                                                    }
```

Comment: I doubt java can execute anything on windows network (under \\h try with a local version of the MSI

Comment: It looks like you are trying to launch an IE 8 fixer. Why can't you run this by double clicking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows installer is in %windir%\msiexec.exe
An MSI file is not standalone. It needs to be run like `msiexec \"file.msi\"`
So use:

```
try {
   Runtime rf = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
   Process pf = rf.exec("msiexec /i \"\\IE8fix.msi\"");    
} catch(Exception e) {                 
   //System.out.println(e.toString()); // not necessary       
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: how do I add the slashed for the installs like /a?

Comment: nevermind I figured it out, it goes right after the msiexec and before the \ thanks!

Comment: Here's a good reference for the command: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/msiexec.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: For me it simply works with 
`Process prc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String.format("msiexec /i %s", installationFile));`

Then, streams like `prc.getErrorStream()` are available and can be useful

Answer (score 0):

An .msi file is not a standalone program like an exe, it should run from the Windows Installer something like this (i hope this is correct):

```
Process pf = rf.exec("msiexec \"\\IE8fix.msi\"");
```